Homebrew spell to improve familiar link before combat
Yesterday I was thinking that the standard actions required to manage the familiar
(to see and hear from her, to dismiss and recall her into the pocket dimension, etc) are quite a burden in combat,
so I was thinking of a spell to be cast just ahead of combat.
So I ended up designing this:

Familiar Link
1st-level divination
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 60 feet
Components: S
Duration: 1 minute
For 1 minute while the familiar is within 100 feet of you, her senses are telepathically reported also to you and you are not deaf and blind with regards of your own senses. Also, when this spell is in effect, dismissing or recalling the familiar becomes a free action for you.
The spell temporarily stops working as long as the familiar is into
the pocket dimension.
Establishing such a strong link to receive
sensations from both your body and your familiar's can be challenging:
if you cast the spell two or more times before completing your next long rest, there is a cumulative 25 percent chance for each casting after the first, that you get one level of exhaustion.

Now I am asking: is this balanced?

This looks rather weak
Outside of special circumstances, you have better things to do in combat than look through your familiar who normally cannot attack and has little influence on combat apart from granting advantage with the help action. You could use that same level 1 spell slot to cast hideous laughter, shield or sleep instead to impact the battlefield.
Moreover, unless you know that a fight is coming up, casting this spell will also consume an action, up front. Most fights only take 3-4 rounds, so this is only partially achieving your idea of not having to sacrifice actions to manage your familiar.
How good this is will depend on how lenient your DM is on allowing "free actions" outside your turn. The rules do not formally define a free action, and are somewhat murky on if you can use "free actions" outside your turn, but probably not. See also When can you do things that do not require an action? The PHB just says (p. 190) that Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move. These activities like talking are allowed on "Your turn"1. Potentially dismissing and recalling as a free action could help you protect your familiar from being attacked by anything but a Readied action when you only bring them in to grant advantage on attacks and a persistent source of advantage on attacks is good, but this will really depend on how your DM rules, and the likely answer is that you cannot do that, in which case this has little value.
The benefits for this certainly are in no need to also add the rather harsh punishment of exhaustion to it. In general adding drawbacks to balance a powerful effect is problematic, more so if they are randomly determined, because that can lead to extremely swingy outcomes; but this is not a powerful effect.
One often does not know how good or bad something is until one has playtested it, so if you really want to know I recommend you do that; but if I were a player, I would be unlikely to pick, prepare or cast this spell.

1 Many tables allow speaking short messages outside your turn anyways, but if it comes to actions that materially affect combat, allowing them out of turn in spite of the rules seems a lot less likely.
P.S. There is another technical issue with the description. If "the spell temporarily stops working while the familiar is in the pocket dimension", then it is not working while the familiar is dismissed, and getting it back would cost an action, via the function of the normal find familiar spell. You can probably just remove that sentence, as I imagine that is not what you have in mind.

Balanced... yes. Clean... no.
First, it's a little odd that the range of the spell is 60 feet while the normal telepathic range for a familiar is 100 feet. Second, you're repeating a lot of the text of the find familiar spell, you could just say the part about how "you are not deaf and blind with regard to your own senses" while seeing and hearing through your familiar. Third, we can not refer needlessly to free actions, you can just say that once on your turn you may either temporarily dismiss your familiar or return it from temporary dismissal without requiring an action. Fifth, you don't need to specify that the spell temporarily stops working while in the pocket dimension, as that qualifies as being more than 100 feet from you as it is on another plane of existence. Sixth, the entire exhaustion clause is pretty unnecessary, and isn't really needed for balance, you're already spending an action and a spell slot for this, and not really gaining very much except a little utility.
Below is an edited spell description

Familiar Link
1st-level divination
Casting Time: 1 action
Range: 100 feet
Components: S
Duration: 1 minute
For 1 minute you see through your familiar’s eyes and hear what it hears, as long as it remains in the spell's range, and you are not deaf and blind with regards of your own senses. Also, once on each of your turns, you may temporarily dismiss the familiar or recall it without requiring an action.

